# Spree | Price per unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I want to provide price per unit for some type of products.

For example:

- I sell a lot of contructing stuff in my shop.
- Let's take laminate for this example. I want to specify price for one square meter of it.
- So 1 m^2 of laminate costs 10$. This price i want to set manualy.
- In laminate pack there is fixed amount of laminate, for example, 2.5
  m^2. I will set it mannualy too.
- So price per pack will be calculated as 25$. It will set automatically. User must see price per unit - 10$/m^2, price per pack - 25$ and can buy only packs.

Is there any exsistent way or plugin to do it in spree? Or any best practise to do it elegant and dry?

Comment: Do you ever need to sell packs of different sizes? The easy way seems to be to just add an extra column called unit price and put it on both the product page and the product admin page which is simply a text input you type "$10 per m^2" and you put the pack size somewhere else on the page.

Comment: @Qwertie yes, sell packs is different sizes. I can just calculate price with js on pages with certain type of products, but it seems awkward